# Find points which make the tangent plane horizontal?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

I'm wondering if someone could give me some hints as to how to approach this question, or some theory to understand what it's actually asking:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tangent plane at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ to a surface given in an implicit equation $F(x,y,z)=0$ is given by
$$F_x(x_0,y_0,z_0)(x-x_0)+F_y(x_0,y_0,z_0)(y-y_0)+F_z(x_0,y_0,z_0)(z-z_0)=0.$$
Can you take it from here? How do you recognize an horizontal plane?

Answer (score 0):

$F(x,y,z) =0$ is the surface, let $P := (x_0,y_0z_0) $ be a point on the surface.

Normal vector  $\vec n$  to the surface at $P$ is:

$\vec n = (F_x(P),F_y(P),F_z(P)).$

This normal vector  specifies the tangent plane to the surface.

If the normal points in the $z$ direction,

the plane is horizontal (|| to x-y plane).

Hence :

$(2x+2,2y-4,2z) =a(0,0,1)$,

where  $a \in \mathbb{R}.$

$\rightarrow:$

$x=-1, y=2, z =a/2.$

The point $(x,y,z)$ is a point on the surface.

$F(x=-1,y=2, z=a/2) =0$.

Left to do: Find $a$.

Then your tangent plane:

$\vec n \cdot ( \vec r - (x_0,y_0,z_0))= 0$

where  $(x_0=-2 ,y_0 =2 , z_0= a/2)$

and  $\vec n=a(0,0,1).$

Note: You may find two values for $a$.

What does it mean?